# PCI function number for SATA AHCI controller

Tags: hardware

I'm debugging a second stage boot loader for a PC with SATA AHCI controller. I'm able to enumerate the PCI bus and find the hard disk. So far, so good. Now, lspci in my notebook (Dell Inspiron 1525) show me:

```
-[0000:00]-+-1f.0  Intel Corporation 82801HEM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller
           +-1f.1  Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation 82801HBM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA AHCI Controller
           \-1f.3  Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller
```

My question: Is SATA AHCI Controller always function 2 in any PC? If not, how I found?

I don't pretend to be general; booting my notebook will be good enough, without compromise further refinements.

Answer (score 1):

Compliant SATA AHCI controllers should always have Device class 1 (storage controller) subclass 6 (Serial ATA) and interface 1 (AHCI). So the correct strategy is to enumerate all the PCI devices and compare their class, subclass and interface to identify those which implements AHCI. Note that there may be more than one, depending on the mainboard and whether any other AHCI cards are plugged into it.

You may want to also allow your code to match an AHCI controller by the vendor and device ID, because some early AHCI controllers don't have the appropriate class/subclass/interface set.